# How can I protect Midori from poodle

Tags: ssl, midori

How can I protect midori from poodle?
I have found fixes for Firefox and Chrome but not for midori.

Comment: That question only covers Firefox and Chrome

Comment: ssl support on midori is poorly supported in debian /ubuntu. You might need to post your question to the midori mailing list. See - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=607497 "It has been decided that since Midori's
support for SSL is inherently limited that this fix won't be applied
for squeeze.  It is currently recommended to not use midori if SSL
support is important to you.  Epiphany or chromium are the preferred
webkit-based browsers."

Comment: You can try #midori on freenode, https://code.launchpad.net/midori , and / or https://github.com/eustasy/midori-browser.org/issues

Comment: That link is the best we have on Poodle